# ngCordova - Cannot get SQLite records

Tags: sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I'm wondering what i'm doing wrong here, it's hell to debug it like most of cordova plugins...

I'm simply trying to store a few strings... (I only need it in one controller)

```
var db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({ name: "videos" });
$cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS videos (id integer primary key, video mediumtext)");

// getting some data from the server, nothing special

query = "INSERT INTO videos (id, video) VALUES (?)";
$cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, [response.Data.media]).then(function(result) {
  console.log(result);
  var message = "INSERT ID -> " + result.insertId;
  console.log(message);
}, function (err) {
  console.error(err);
  //alert(err);
});
```

I get the inserted ID, so it must be saving something... But when I try to load it using a function

```
var query = "SELECT * FROM videos where id = 1";
$cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query).then(function(result) {
  console.log(result);
});
```

I get nothing.

[image]

Astrophysicists would call it empty space, but we are developers and we need data to process! Why is there nothing in rows? (no matter if I select where id or everything, it is just showing me this kind of empty object with no data).

Much thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to loop over the result like this:

```
var output = [];
for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
    output.push(result.rows.item(i));
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(output));
```

Then when you look at output it will contain an array of results with data.